# COND clause with test only

Tags: common-lisp

When `COND` is given only one test clause and nothing else at all it always returns the test result:

```
 CL-USER> (cond (t))
    T
 CL-USER>  (cond ((> 5 10)))
    NIL
```

Isn't `COND` just a way to write `IF` statements? 
This doesn't hold for this as when rewriting  `COND` with  test only:

```
    CL-USER> (if (> 5 1))    
    error while parsing arguments to DESTRUCTURING-BIND:
  too few elements in
    ((> 5 1))
  to satisfy lambda list
    (SB-IMPL::TEST SB-IMPL::THEN &OPTIONAL SB-IMPL::ELSE):
  between 2 and 3 expected, but got 1
```

If it is this way then how does  `COND` exactly transform every clause into `IF` version?

Comment: Use `macroexpand` to expand forms using COND and check the generated code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *When COND is given only one test clause and nothing else at all it always returns the test result:*

That's right. According to the HyperSpec entry on [**cond**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_cond.htm):

> results---the values of the forms in the first clause whose test-form yields true, or the primary value of the test-form if there are no forms in that clause, or else nil if no test-form yields true.

> *Isn't COND just a way to write IF statements?*

Well, **cond** is declared to be a macro, and [**if**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_if.htm#if) to be a special operator, so you can think of it that way, although the expansion of **cond** isn't defined specifically. But **if** is defined with syntax that requires a *then-part*, whereas **cond** isn't.  Here's what a **cond** clause with no forms expands to (in SBCL):

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand '(cond ((+ 2 3)))))

(LET ((#:G1013 (+ 2 3)))
  (IF #:G1013
      #:G1013
      (COND)))
```

The value of the form is saved in a value and then used as the *then-part*. When there *are* forms in the clause, they're wrapped in a **progn** (which returns the value of its last form):

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand 
                  '(cond
                    ((= 2 3) 42 78)
                    ((+ 2 3))
                    ((= 4 5) (print 'something-else)))))

(IF (= 2 3)
    (PROGN 42 78)
    (COND ((+ 2 3)) ((= 4 5) (PRINT 'SOMETHING-ELSE))))
```